# provided object has contents but it is undefined when injected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown below in the code, in the `provider.vue` i provide the value of `reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance`. inside the `watch` option in the `provider.vue`, i make sure that the `reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance.value` has value by printing the contents of
it as shown in the log statement. the output of that log statement inidicates that `reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance.value` has value/contents.

however, in the `injector.vue`, i inject the value as shown below in the code. the `injector.vue` has a toggle-button, when its value changes, it causes `isToggleBtnClearDigitizedCheckState` to change accordingly, but then, the injected value of `this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance`
generated the error posted below indicating that `this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance` is `undefined`

please let me know what i have done wrong and how to correct it

**provider.vue**:

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance: {
            value: undefined,
        },
    };
},
provide() {
    return {
        [InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_CLASS_DIGITIZE_POLYGON_INTERACTIONS_INSTANCE.description]: this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance,
    };
},
watch: {
    'injMapInstance.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log({msg:verboseTag + ' watched injMapInstance is called where oldVal: ' + oldVal + ', and newVal: ' + newVal});
        if (oldVal == undefined && newVal != undefined) {
            if (this.injMapInstance) {
                if (this.injMapInstance.value) {
                    if (newVal != undefined && oldVal != undefined && newVal != oldVal) {
                        const msg = JSON.stringify({msg:WTFTag + 'value of injMapInstance.value is defined and changed from:' + oldVal + ' to: ' + newVal});
                        throw new Error(msg);
                    }
                    if (clsDigitizePolygonInteractions) {
                        clsDigitizePolygonInteractions.setMapInstance(this.injMapInstance.value);
                        this.polygonDigitizationProgressStatus = clsDigitizePolygonInteractions.listenToDigitizationProgressStatus();
                        this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance.value = clsDigitizePolygonInteractions;
                        
                        //the following log statement indicates that `this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance.value` has value              <<<<<<<==========================================
                        const msg = JSON.stringify({msg:WTFTag + 'reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance: ' + JSON.stringify(this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance.value, null, 4)});
                        console.log(debugTag, '###msg:', msg)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
```

**injector.vue**:

```
export default {
    inject: {
        injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_CLASS_DIGITIZE_POLYGON_INTERACTIONS_INSTANCE.description },
    },
    watch: {
        isToggleBtnClearDigitizedCheckState(newVal, oldVal) {
            this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance.value.clear(); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<==============================it generated the error posted below
        },
    }
}
```

**error generated by `watch` option in injector.vue**:

```
vue:69 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
at Proxy.isToggleBtnClearDigitizedCheckState (ToggleButtonClearDigit
```

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce. It would be like that if injector weren't a child of provider

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, the injector is not a child?would that matter?please explain and tell me how to overcome this situation please

Comment: @EstusFlask is it a rule that the two components must be in a child-parent relation so the mechanism of provide-inject works?i thought the any components can be provider and injector

Comment: Of course, that's the sole purpose of provide/inject, to make dependency injection based on component hierarchy, can be done on any level. Without that, stick to global store, that's the perfect case for that. You don't need vuex or pinia for a simple store, see https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

Comment: @EstusFlask just to make sure that i got you right, you confirm that provide-inject must be applied between parent-child relation, otherwise the global store must be used. right?

Comment: @EstusFlask would you please have a look at this one as well:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77111740/attempted-to-get-private-field-on-non-instance-when-passing-object-reference-fro                                                                   aslo, for this question if you posted an answer i will accept it

Comment: @Amr yes either a global store or composables should be used when the components are not directly in the same hierarchy