# attempted to get private field on non-instance when passing object reference from parent to child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `option api`

as shown below in the code, in the `ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon.vue` is a child to `NDVIComparisonGUI`.in the latter one, i instantiate an object of `clsDigitizePolygonInteractions` in `created()` and in `watch` option, i set the object reference instantiated
to the reactive object `reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance` as follows

```
provide() {
        return {
            [InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_CLASS_DIGITIZE_POLYGON_INTERACTIONS_INSTANCE.description]: this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance,
        };
    },
this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance.value = clsDigitizePolygonInteractions
```

the provided object mentioned above, will be injected inot `ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon.vue` as shown in the code. when the toggle button in `ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon.vue` is toggled i want to call the method `digitize()` on the object reference that was
injected into `ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon` as shown in the code.

what happens at run time is, when `digitize()` is called, i receive the following error:

```
classPrivateMethodGet.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: attempted to get private field on non-instance
```

to sum up, i want to pass the object reference that was instantiated in `NDVIComparisonGUI` to the child component `ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon`.

please let me know how to over come this error and how to correct it

**ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon.vue**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {...};
    },
    inject: {
        injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_CLASS_DIGITIZE_POLYGON_INTERACTIONS_INSTANCE.description },
    },
    ,
    watch: {
        isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonCheckState(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance) {
                console.log({msg:verboseTag + ' watched isToggleBtnDigitizePolygonCheckState is called where oldVal: '  + oldVal + ', and newVal: '+ newVal});
                if (newVal == true && oldVal == false) {
                    console.log('###this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance.value:',this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance.value)
                    this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance.value.digitize();
                } else if (newVal == false && oldVal == true) {
                    this.injClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsMapInstance.value.deattachAll();
                }
            } 
        },
    }
```

**NDVIComparisonGUI.vue**:

```
<ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon
    v-model:vModelToggleDigitize="vModelToggleDigitize"
    @onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsInstanceInit="onClsDigitizePolygonInteractionsInstanceInitt">
</ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon>

<ToggleButtonClearDigitized
    v-model:vModelToggleClearDigitized="vModelToggleClearDigitized">
</ToggleButtonClearDigitized>

<script>

let clsDigitizePolygonInteractions = undefined;

export default {
    name: 'NDVIComparisonGUI',
    data() {
        return {
            vModelToggleDigitize: false,
            vModelToggleClearDigitized: false,
            reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance: {
                value: undefined,
            },
        };
    },
    ,
    components: {
        ToggleButtonDigitizePolygon,
        ToggleButtonClearDigitized,
    },
    provide() {
        return {
            [InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_CLASS_DIGITIZE_POLYGON_INTERACTIONS_INSTANCE.description]: this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance,
        };
    },
    inject: {
        injMapInstance: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description },
    },
    watch: {
        'injMapInstance.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log({msg:verboseTag + 'watch.injMapInstance is called where oldVal: ' + oldVal + ', and newVal: ' + newVal});
            if (oldVal == undefined && newVal != undefined) {
                if (this.injMapInstance) {
                    if (this.injMapInstance.value) {
                        if (newVal != undefined && oldVal != undefined && newVal != oldVal) {
                            const msg = JSON.stringify({msg:WTFTag + 'value of injMapInstance.value is defined and changed from:' + oldVal + ' to: ' + newVal});
                            throw new Error(msg);
                        }
                        if (clsDigitizePolygonInteractions) {
                            clsDigitizePolygonInteractions.setMapInstance(this.injMapInstance.value);
                            this.polygonDigitizationProgressStatus = clsDigitizePolygonInteractions.listenToDigitizationProgressStatus();
                            this.reactRefClsDigitizePolygonInstance.value = clsDigitizePolygonInteractions;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
    created() {
        console.log(verboseTag, 'created()');
        clsDigitizePolygonInteractions = new ClsDigitizePolygonInteractions(SysConstants.PRENEWS_MAP_MODULE_NAME.description);
    },
}
```

Comment: It's not shown what clsDigitizePolygonInteractions is, while it's relevant. Currently it looks like class instance mangled when assigned to component state. Try to use `.value = markRaw(clsDigitizePolygonInteractions)`

Comment: @EstusFlask regarding ‘ clsDigitizePolygonInteractions’ it is an object instantiated in created() in the parent component

Comment: @EstusFlask good morning, did my last comment make it clearer for you please?also, you mentioned that composables can be used to solve this issue, how that is possible please? I mean how I can use it to solve this issue please

Comment: Should be what's in the previous comment, use markRaw

Comment: @EstusFlask it is working now after using markraw()

Comment: @EstusFlask hi, just iin case you are interested in answering this please:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77126747/how-to-force-toggle-button-to-be-toggled-off

Comment: @EstusFlask hallo, I have a question please, is it possible to use provide/inject to pass data from child to parent component?i tried it but that data from the child does not arrive to the parent!

Comment: Hi. It works in one direction. You can provide an object from a parent and call its methods or modify data in a child. If there are not supposed to be multiple objects of the same kind in the app, it makes more sense to just use global store instead

Comment: @EstusFlask good morning, can I use event emitter to pass data from child to parent instead of global store please?

Comment: This is what events are for. Global store and provide/inject are to interact with grand-parents, etc

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, so, both of provide-inject and global store are for passing data from parents to childern, right? and to pass data from child to parent events should be used, right?

Comment: They are to pass data between deeply nested components where the use of props and events is possible but uncomfortable. For direct parent-child relation use props and events.