# How to force toggle button to be toggled off?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

I am using `vue3` with `options api`
for the code contained in the following `stackbiltz` [code is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5g2yjc?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue).

I have a `toggle-button` and I want to set it to be toggled off automatically after 3 seconds. To achieve that, as shown in the following code

```
methods: {
    onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = false
      }, 3000);
        
    },
},
```

I set `compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn` to `false` after 3 seconds but that did not make the toggle button toggle off.

I want the toggle button when toggled on to be toggled off after 3 seconds elapse.

How can I achieve that please?

Comment: This presumes the state of this field is supposed to be handled in a parent component, like `<HelloWorld v-model:vModelToggleClearDigitized=...`. Currently update:vModelToggleClearDigitized emits to nowhere. I'd suggest to reduce the complexity and check how two-way binding works in Vue, as this was discussed in earlier questions

Comment: @EstusFlask morning, do want to answer this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132029/onclick-of-a-button-does-not-change-clickability-state

Comment: @EstusFlask morning, can you please answer this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155195/how-to-use-global-store

Comment: @EstusFlask is the global-state can not be watcher?i created a global store and i tried to watch a reactive getter method, but the watch option never executes..any idea please?

Comment: @EstusFlask morning, would you please tell me whther it is recommended to let two child component communicate directly via event-emitter? or they should communicate with eachother via parent component?

Comment: Hi, it's not possible for them to communicate directly, they do this through a common parent

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="toggleButton" :class="{ active: isButtonActive }">
      {{ isButtonActive ? 'ON' : 'OFF' }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isButtonActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleButton() {
      this.isButtonActive = !this.isButtonActive;
      if (this.isButtonActive) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.isButtonActive = false;
        }, 3000);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please modify the stack blitz code

Comment: Sorry, I cannot edit code.

Comment: ok no problem but it does not work anyhow

Comment: Look here, what's wrong?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-dgkgrp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Comment: oh sorry, maybe i did something wrong, but i would like to use the approach i am following in my question please

Comment: Add this line of code, it will be fixed.
data() {
    return {
      state: false,
      compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn: false
    };
  },