# onClick of a button does not change clickability state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown in the below posted code, when the `checkbox` is clicked, the `onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged()` is called causing the `state` to change from `false` to `true`, and for the following line in the same method:

```
this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = this.state;
```

i assign the new value assigned to `this.satate` to `this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn` which should be `true`, but surprisingly, the log statement

```
console.log('##compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn);
```

prints the value of `this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn` is `false`. how that is possible? because `this.state = !this.state` and then the value of `this.state` is assigned to `this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn`

**link to code:

[link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-5g2yjc?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue)

**output**:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Ehu.png)

**code**:

```
<template>
  <cds-toggle id="idToggleBtnClearDigitized" class="clsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon">
        <label for="toggling-digitization-of-polygon-on-and-off">
            {{ toggleBtnClearDigitizedLabel }}
        </label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            :value="compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn', $event.target.value)"
            :disabled="isToggleBtnClearDigitizedDisabled"
            @change="onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged()"
            :checked="compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn"
        />
    </cds-toggle>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            state: false,
        };
    },
    props: {
        toggleBtnClearDigitizedLabel: {
            type: String,
            default: 'clear',
        },
        isToggleBtnClearDigitizedDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
        vModelToggleClearDigitized: {
            type: undefined,
            default:true
        },
    },
    emits: ['update:vModelToggleClearDigitized'],
    computed: {
        compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + this.vModelToggleClearDigitized);
                return this.vModelToggleClearDigitized;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelToggleClearDigitized', value);
            },
        },
    },
    watch: {
        isToggleBtnClearDigitizedDisabled(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log( 'watch.isToggleBtnClearDigitizedDisabled.newVal:' + newVal);
            console.log('watch.isToggleBtnClearDigitizedDisabled.oldVal:' + oldVal);
        },
        state(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log( 'watch.state.newVal:' + newVal);
            console.log('watch.state.oldVal:' + oldVal);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged() {
            this.state = !this.state   
            this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = this.state;
            console.log('##state:' + this.state);
            console.log('##compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn);
            if (this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn == true) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = false
                }, 3000);
            }
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because you are logging the value of `this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn` immediately after updating it. Due to Vue's asynchronous nature, the prop update doesn't take effect immediately.

To ensure that you are logging the updated value, you can utilize Vue's `nextTick` method to wait until the DOM updates to log the new values. Update your `onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged` method as follows:

```
onToggleBtnClearDigitizedChanged() {
    this.state = !this.state   
    this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = this.state;
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        console.log('##state:' + this.state);
        console.log('##compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn:' + this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn);
    });
    if (this.state == true) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.compPropsVModelToggleClearDigitizedBtn = false
        }, 3000);
    }
},
```

And one more thing. These names are the longest ones that I've seen in my whole life! Please consider shorter names for variables for cleaner code.

Comment: thanks. For the names of the variables, i want to have descriptive names as the project i am working on is huge and will consume too much time, using such names will make it easier for me know later which variable was for which#