# How to use global-store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component, composable

I am using `vue3` with `options api`

I am learning how to use `global-store` i referred to the official website of `vue`, and read some posts in forums.
As shown in the code in the following link:

[link to stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-cwdjqy?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2Fstore%2FStoreMajorEnableState.vue)

I create `StoreMajorEnableState.vue` as composable, but I am getting this error

```
app.js:191 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__vccOpts')
at exports.default (exportHelper.js:6:1)
at eval (StoreMajorEnableState.vue:5:1)
at ./src/store/StoreMajorEnableState.vue (app.js:99:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:188:33)
at fn (app.js:422:21)
at eval (index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:2:90)
at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (app.js:29:1)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:188:33)
at fn (app.js:422:21)
at eval (HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:5:213)
```

and i do not know how to solve it
please help me to solve this error, and please tell me how to use the `globla-store` correctly

Comment: Please, add the relevant code to the question itself, it needs to be intelligible even if external link is unavailable. You shouldn't use .vue for anything but components. This is regular JS script, it goes to .js or .ts. Store getters can be reactive but they need to use reactive api. getters.getMajorEnableState needs to be called by watch() or computed() in order to be reactive

Comment: @EstusFlask i created this example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xltavx?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2Fstore%2FStoreMajorEnableState.js  would you please show me how to make the getter of a store reactive?

Comment: @EstusFlask referring to the link of stackbiltz i sent in my previous message, in the App.vue i added the following: watch: {
    'storeMajorEnableState_.state'(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log('watch storeMajorEnableState_.newVal:', newVal)
      console.log('watch storeMajorEnableState_.oldVal:', oldVal)
    },
  }, but still not reactive

Comment: getMajorEnableState is a function, so it should be `this.$watch(this.storeMajorEnableState_.getters.getMajorEnableState, () => ...)` inside created() hook. Or better use computed() for getters when you create a store

Comment: @EstusFlask isn’t that composition api?!i am using optional api please

Comment: Yes. You're already using reactive() for the store. It doesn't matter, Vue 3 uses composition everywhere under the hood, there's a bridge for options syntax

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you, I will acknowledge once I test it.

Comment: @EstusFlask hi, I would like to know your opinion about this problem please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77171663/how-to-uncheck-radio-button