# How to uncheck radio button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown below in the code, i have a `radio button`, with `checked` property is set to `compPropsVModelCodeDE`.i want when the `injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns` in the `watch` option is triggered, to set `compPropsVModelCodeDE` to false so
that that `radio button` is unchecked.

i tried the following

```
watch: {
    'injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('#####newVal:', newVal, ' oldVal:', oldVal)
        if (newVal == false) {
            this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.compPropsVModelCodeDE = false
            })
        }
    },
},
```

but that did not cause the radio button to be unchecked.
please let me know how to uncheck the radio button

**code**:

```
<template>
    <cds-radio id="idRadioButtonCodeDEContainer">
        <label>{{ tempTextCodeDE }}</label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            :value="compPropsVModelCodeDE"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelCodeDE', $event.target.value)"
            :disabled="isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled"
            :checked="compPropsVModelCodeDE"
            @change="onCodeDESelected()"
        />
    </cds-radio>
</template>

<script>
import { InjectionKeys } from '../../../../map/assets/System/InjectionKeys.js';
export default {
    name: 'RadioButtonCodeDE',
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        tempTextCodeDE: {
            type: String,
            default: 'ProcessingEngines',
        },
        vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE: {
            type: undefined,
        },
        isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
    },
    inject: {
        injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_CHECK_STATE_OF_SAT_DATA_PROCESSING_ENGINES_RADIO_BUTTONS.description },
    },
    emits: {
        'update:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE': null,
    },
    watch: {
        'injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('#####newVal:', newVal, ' oldVal:', oldVal)
            if (newVal == false) {
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.compPropsVModelCodeDE = false
                })
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsVModelCodeDE: {
            get() {
                console.log(debugTag, '@get.compPropsVModelCodeDE:', this.compPropsVModelSentinelHub);
                return this.compPropsVModelCodeDE;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log(debugTag, '@set.compPropsVModelCodeDE:', this.compPropsVModelCodeDE);
                this.$emit('update:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onCodeDESelected() {
            console.log('onCodeDESelected');
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style>
    @import '../../../../map/assets/css/radioButtonCodeDEContainer.css';
</style>
```

Comment: Depending on the case, you may want to make injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns watcher immediate, and $nextTick isn't needed. Otherwise it may work, this depends on other parts that aren't shown

Comment: @EstusFlask morning, i think, if this one is solved:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77177298/v-model-in-the-parent-component-does-not-get-fired             it could be the reason why this one is not solved..do you think so please

Comment: The link is not available

Comment: @EstusFlask yes, I intentionally deleted it because I solved it, but I un-deleted it again

Comment: @EstusFlask good morning,  can you please answer this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77227228/how-to-cause-data-picker-to-fire-v-model