# v-model in the parent component does not get fired

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown below in the code, in the child-component, i have a `radio-button` with its all properties needed to establish `v-model` shown in the template. in the parent-component i create the `v-model` as follows

```
<RadioButtonCodeDE
    v-model:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE="vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE"
    ...
    ...
    ...
></RadioButtonCodeDE>
```

when the `injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns` is changed in the child component, it causes `compPropsVModelCodeDE` to be set to false, causing the computed property `compPropsVModelCodeDE` in the child-component to changed, hence the event-emitter
`this.$emit('update:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE', value);`

the problem is, when the `this.$emit('update:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE', value);` is executed, the `watched` property in the parent-component`vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE` does not get executed despite the log message in the child-componenet represented in
the setter method of the computed property executes as shown in the following code

```
computed: {
    compPropsVModelCodeDE: {
        get() {
            console.log(debugTag, '@get.compPropsVModelCodeDE:', this.vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE);
            return this.vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE;
        },
        set(value) {
            console.log(debugTag, '@set.compPropsVModelCodeDE:', value);//<<<=====this log gets executed
            this.$emit('update:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE', value);
        },
    },
},
```

please let me know why the `v-model` in the parent component does not get executed or fired

**child component**:

```
<template>
    <cds-radio id="idRadioButtonCodeDEContainer">
        <label>{{ tempTextCodeDE }}</label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            :value="compPropsVModelCodeDE"
            @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelCodeDE', $event.target.value)"
            :disabled="isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled"
            :checked="compPropsVModelCodeDE"
            @change="onCodeDESelected()"
        />
    </cds-radio>
</template>

<script>
import { ProcessingEnginesRadioButtonsConstants } from '../../resources/ProcessingEnginesRadioButtonsConstants';
import { InjectionKeys } from '../../../../map/assets/System/InjectionKeys.js';

export default {
    name: 'RadioButtonCodeDE',
    data() {
        return {};
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        tempTextCodeDE: {
            type: String,
            default: ProcessingEnginesRadioButtonsConstants.CONST_STRING_PROCESSING_ENGINE_CODE_DE.description,
        },
        vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE: {
            type: null,
        },
        isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
    },
    inject: {
        injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_CHECK_STATE_OF_SAT_DATA_PROCESSING_ENGINES_RADIO_BUTTONS.description },
    },
    emits: ['update:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE'],
    watch: {
        'injCheckStateOfSatDataProcessingEnginesRadioBtns.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('#####newVal:', newVal, ' oldVal:', oldVal);
            if (newVal == false) {
                this.compPropsVModelCodeDE = false;
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsVModelCodeDE: {
            get() {
                console.log(debugTag, '@get.compPropsVModelCodeDE:', this.vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE);
                return this.vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log(debugTag, '@set.compPropsVModelCodeDE:', value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onCodeDESelected() {
            console.log('onCodeDESelected');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**parent component**:

```
<template>
    <cds-radio-group id="idSatelliteDateProcessnigEnginesRadioButtonsLayoutContainer" name="satelliteDataProcessingEngines" layout="" cds-layout="p-y:lg">
        <label id="idSatelliteDataProcessingEnginesLabel"> {{ tempTextSDPEngines }} </label>
        <RadioButtonCodeDE
            v-model:vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE="vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE"
            v-bind:isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled="isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled"
        ></RadioButtonCodeDE>
        <RadioButtonSentinelHub
            v-bind:isRadioButtonSentinelHubDisabled="isRadioButtonSentinelHubDisabled"
        ></RadioButtonSentinelHub>
    </cds-radio-group>
</template>

<script>
import RadioButtonCodeDE from './RadioButtonCodeDE.vue';
import RadioButtonSentinelHub from './RadioButtonSentinelHub.vue';
import { ProcessingEnginesRadioButtonsConstants } from './../../resources/ProcessingEnginesRadioButtonsConstants';
import { InjectionKeys } from './../../../../map/assets/System/InjectionKeys.js';

export default {
    name: 'ProcessingEnginesLayoutContainer',
    data() {
        return {
            tempTextSDPEngines: ProcessingEnginesRadioButtonsConstants.CONST_STRING_SATELLITE_DATE_PROCESSING_ENGINE_SENTINEL_HUB.description,
            isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled: true,
            isRadioButtonSentinelHubDisabled: true,
            vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE: false,
        };
    },
    components: {
        RadioButtonCodeDE,
        RadioButtonSentinelHub,
    },
    inject: {
        injMajorLayoutEnable: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_MAJOR_ENABLE.description },
    },
    watch: {
        // passing the majorLayoutEnable state to child components via properties
        'injMajorLayoutEnable.value'(newVal, oldVal) {
            const msg = JSON.stringify({msg:verboseTag + '@watch injMajorLayoutEnable.value', where:'newVal: ' + newVal + ' and oldVal: ' + oldVal});
            console.log(msg);
            if (newVal == true && oldVal == false) {
                this.isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled = false;
                this.isRadioButtonSentinelHubDisabled = false;
            } else if (newVal == false && oldVal == true) {
                this.isRadioButtonCodeDEDisabled = true;
                this.isRadioButtonSentinelHubDisabled = true;
            }
        },
        vModelProcessingEnginCodeDE(newVal, oldVal) { //<<<<<====== the logs here never get printed
            console.log('-->>newval: ',newVal);
            console.log('-->>oldVal: ',oldVal);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```