# How to cause data-picker to trigger v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

given the code posted in `stackbiltz`, when i change the date in the date-picker, i expect that the `computed-property` `compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo` is to be fired causing the log-statements in

```
    compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo: {
        get() {
            console.log('get.compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo:', this.vModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo);
            return this.vModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo;
        },
        set(value) {
            console.log('set.compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo:', value);
            this.$emit('update:vModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo', value);
        },
    },
```

to display. but what happens is, when i change the date, only the method `onDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToChanged()` is called.

please let me know how to make the computed property `compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo` fires as the date changes.

**link to stackbiltz**

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-kasehp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue,src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: It's the same problem as occurred in the previous questions. You should have a state in data() named vModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo in order to watch it.

Comment: @EstusFlask i added `,
        vModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo: {
          type: null
        }` to `data` but still v-model does not get triggered..pls see the stackbiltz example

Comment: The demo doesn't work because of an error, Property assignment expected. I suspect there's a problem on stackblitz side.

Comment: @EstusFlask maybe because i updated the code, but did not save it..i saved it now

Comment: It's onDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoToChanged that is triggered, it does nothing. You carried all that useless props in <input> through several questions. If you stick to that writable computed which makes the example unnecessarily complicated then at least you can make it useful, <input v-model="compPropsVModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo"> . That's what v-model is actually for.

Comment: @EstusFlask referring to the same question, the set(value) of the computed-property is called, but `vModelDatePickerTimeSeriesAgoTo` in the parent does not get called please

Comment: I see the watcher is triggered in the parent https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-dyborx